# android onclick listener not opening desired activity

Tags: android

I have made an android app with some activities. The issue is in my login activity there is a text called " new user, reg here". When I click on that, it should go to Reg.java page. But instead, it is just reloading the same page.
I have checked my manifest, it's fine. Also, I tried to link this textView with another activity and it works fine. But it is not working with Reg.java.

Code:

```
LoginActivity.java
package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private EditText etusername, etid;
     Button btnlogin;
     TextView tvreg;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    private final int LoginTask = 1;
    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);
        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

        etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvreg);

        tvreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                **Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Reg.class);
                startActivity(intent);**
            }
        });

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    login();
                } catch (IOException |JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void login() throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.NAME, etusername.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.MI_ID, etid.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(AndyConstants.ServiceType.LOGIN);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result,LoginTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void onTaskCompleted(String response, int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case LoginTask:
                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Reg.java

```
        package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import org.json.JSONException;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        public class Reg extends AppCompatActivity {

            private EditText etid, etname, etemail, etphone;
            Button btnregister;
            TextView tvlogin;
            private ParseContent parseContent;
            PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;
            private final int RegTask = 5;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

                preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
                parseContent = new ParseContent(this);

                if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Reg.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();
                }
                etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmi_id);
                etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
                //etstorename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etstore_name);
                etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
                etphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphone);
                //etdoj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdoj);
                btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
                tvlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);

                tvlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Reg.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            register();
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            private void register() throws IOException, JSONException {

                if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(Reg.this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(Reg.this);
                final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put(AndyConstants.Params.MI_ID, etid.getText().toString());
                map.put(AndyConstants.Params.NAME, etname.getText().toString());
               // map.put(AndyConstants.Params.STORE_NAME, etstorename.getText().toString());
                map.put(AndyConstants.Params.EMAIL, etemail.getText().toString());
                map.put(AndyConstants.Params.PHONE, etphone.getText().toString());
               // map.put(AndyConstants.Params.DOJ, etdoj.getText().toString());
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
                    protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                        String response="";
                        try {
                            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(AndyConstants.ServiceType.REGISTER);
                            response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            response=e.getMessage();
                        }
                        return response;
                    }
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        //do something with response
                        Log.d("newwwss", result);
                        onTaskCompleted(result, RegTask);
                    }
                }.execute();
            }

            private void onTaskCompleted(String response, int task) {
                Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
                AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
                switch (task) {
                    case RegTask:

                        if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {

                            parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                            Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Reg.this,Home.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            this.finish();

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(Reg.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mi.mikpiadmin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="KPI"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity android:name=".See_Feedback"
            android:label="Feedback"/>

        <activity android:name=".Reg"
            android:label="Registration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Adminhome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adminhome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity android:name=".Admin_store_contacts"
            android:label="Store Contacts"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a log and check the value of `preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()` when you enter the Reg activity; I am sure it's `true` and the reload you see it's because of this part of code:

```
 if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Reg.this,LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
            }
```